# Adding Animation while switching to dark mode HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-animations

I created a dark mode for my webpage by following the link https://dev.to/ananyaneogi/create-a-dark-light-mode-switch-with-css-variables-34l8
I want to add an animation effect so that when the dark mode is applied, the transition is smooth. How do I do it?

I know CSS keyframes are used to add animations or alternatively jQuery can be used, but I can't seem to get how to use them.

Comment: It's better to include relevant code in your question, as it gives the potential answerer easier access to your problem. Furthermore links may break.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use a [css transition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition). Here follows a simple example, click in the snippet to transition the background color:

```js
const rootDataset = document.documentElement.dataset;

document.onclick = () => {
    const inDarkMode = (rootDataset.theme === 'dark');
    rootDataset.theme = inDarkMode ? '' : 'dark';
}
```

```css
:root {
    --primary-color: beige;    
}
[data-theme="dark"] {
    --primary-color: grey;    
}
body {
    background: var(--primary-color);
    transition: background 2s;
}
```

Comment: Seems good! But in the link I've attached, the method used is creating a custom attribute for the root element and then modifying the value of it on click of the button. So how do I add transition there?

Comment: @user185887 Easily enough adapted for your use-case. I updated the snippet to give you some pointers.